# How to enable debug mode in Samsung Gear Fit SM-R350?

Tags: debugging, samsung-gear-fit

I have a Samsung Gear Fit SM-R350 watch and I want to enable debug on it as I want to develop an android app. 
What I've tried so far is pressing 7 times on Software Version in the About Gear Fit section but it does not work ... 
Is this possible?

Comment: Gear Fit devices are not Android based. Check this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear

Answer (score 0):

I have Gear Fit 2, maybe the procedure is the same;

On the watch in settings/Gear Info: Enable debugging.